# MS Visual Studio 2022 .Net 6 Framework in Razor Pages Project, is this possible?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, razor-pages

I have a question, is it possible to change the target framework for a C# project using Razor Pages from .Net 4.8 to 6.0?

In my project I want to copy files from the local disk to Azure Cloud BlobStorage and currently I can only do it with framework 6.0 or higher. I can't do the switch to the framework from 4.8 to 6.0 because it is not offered to me in this project. What can I do?

I hope that I am not the only one with this problem. Does anyone have any ideas to solve my problem?

Many greetings and thanks in advance

***Code sample, this will work only with .Net 6.0 or higher***

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

//Set <storage-account-name> to actual storage account name
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
    "AccountName=.....;AccountKey=.....;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

//Create a name for the container
string containerName = "myFiles";

//Create the container and return a container client object
BlobContainerClient containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName);

//Create a local file in the directory for uploading and downloading
string localPath = "c:\\DATA";
Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
string fileName = "myFile" + ".txt";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

//Write text to the file
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

//Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

//Upload data from the local file
await blobClient.UploadAsync(localFilePath, true);

Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");

//List all blobs in the container
await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
}

//Download the blob to a local file and append the string "DOWNLOADED" for compare
string downloadFilePath = localFilePath.Replace(".txt", "DOWNLOADED.txt");

Console.WriteLine("\nDownloading blob to\n\t{0}\n", downloadFilePath);

//Download the blob's contents and save it to a file
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(downloadFilePath);

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Comment: 4.8 to 6.0 is not just a version change, it is a different flavor of the framework. you'll likely need to create a multiplatform net60 ASP+razor project first, then add your "already-60" code to that.

Comment: should be possible, try and follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Hi Cee McSharpface, if it were that simple ... i had already tried to create a new C# project + Razor Pages and choose here .net 6 as framework, but this is not provided ... only up to .net 4.8 ... You mean I should create a ASP.NET Core-Web-App (Model View Controller) and add all the Razor stuff?

Comment: Cee McSharpface, thank you very much for this hint, I will try.

Comment: Hello, if you use BlobStorage in your .net4.8 project, will you report such an error?
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'d